# location reload page is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am new to react, would anyone help me on why is F5 and window.location.reload not work same way, please?
In formSubmit method save a survey into database, if response it is ok, reload page by window.location.reload. However it didn't get the data back, page did reload, but if I hit F5, it gets the submitted value back on the page.

```
 formSubmit(guid) {
    console.log("Started");
    fetch("http://localhost:xxxx/api/survey/" + id + "/submit", {
        method:'POST'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok) {
         window.location.reload();
      }
      else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log('catch error');
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think this is the browser saving unsubmitted forms for you.

Comment: Thanks for advice, anyway to solve this, please?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually reload the page.  Check this for ideas about weaving your api calls into your components: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js