# Handle API with react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a quick question.

If I have my API with ky endpointa ready.

Whats is the best approach to handle the calls to api in react and redux.
Is a best way create a class api to fetch the data or what is the right way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: without code examples of what you have tried your question is going to have a hard time here

Comment: look at this https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js

Comment: I Suggest to use axios and redux-thunk, that should solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do my API calls in my React Components, usually from the lifecycle method `componentDidMount` then dispatch my redux actions when the request resolves. That way my redux actions can be entirely synchronous and I don't have to bring in any middleware such as `redux-thunk`. That's just me though, it's perfectly good to use middleware in order to put your API calls in your redux actions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a redux middleware like [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to handle the store behavior and also make writing tests a lot easier.