# How to populate React array from JSON Nodejs back end

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, rest

I'm very new to React.
I've set up a Nodejs back end which reads a JSON file in the following format:

```
{
    "cert1" : {
        "name" : "www.google.com",
        "state" : "valid",
        "days" : "482"
    },
    "cert2" : {
        "name" : "www.facebook.com",
        "state" : "valid",
        "days" : "182"
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to display this data in a table and first need to put it into an array. I've managed to display `www.google.com` using the following code.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name  : '',
    state : '',
    days  : '',
    response : ''
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ 
          response: res.cert1.name
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/list-certs');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          {this.state.response}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I map over the whole JSON file and populate some arrays with all the entries? Right now I'm calling `res.cert1.name` but each cert entry in the JSON file has a different name (cert1, cert2, cert3 etc.) so how do I convert `res.cert1.name` into a generic call for any cert entry in the JSON file?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd want your JSON to be an array, rather than an object of objects:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "www.google.com",
        "state" : "valid",
        "days" : "482"
    }, {
        "name" : "www.facebook.com",
        "state" : "valid",
        "days" : "182"
    }
]
```

Then on the frontend you can grab each cert's name with `res.map(x => x.name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` and `Array.map` to build an array out of your JSON object and map over that to render your elements.

Sample:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        name  : '',
        state : '',
        days  : '',
        response : []
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    response: Object.keys(res).map(key=>({...res[key], id:key}))
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }


    callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/list-certs');
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

        return body;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                </div>
                <p className="App-intro">
                    {this.state.response.map(item => (<p>{item.name}</p>))}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I was getting an error in the browser saying map was not a function

Comment: Sorry, response was initialized as a string. Edited answer. The error was at this line, right? `{this.state.response.map(item => (<p>{item.name}</p>))}`

Comment: I think so yeh, I've changed my JSON file to an array format as suggested above and have changed my response variable to an empty list

Comment: If your JSON is an array now, you can skip the `Object.keys()....` bit in your `componentDidMount` method

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want the json results to be an array.

on retrieval from the api you can set the state with the results.

it depends what your api looks like, however if you return your json object with an array of items in it and store it in the state....

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ 
          results: res.body
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

You can then do a map function in your render.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          { this.state.results.map((row) => {
               return <p>{row.name}</p>
          }) }
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm getting at error in the browser saying:
App.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.response.map is not a function
    at App.render (App.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:793
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:74)

Comment: I've changed the response variable to an array and now there's no error but nothing's being displayed

Comment: Hi @tnoel999888 it could be because the state results is not an array to begin with... in set state use this.setState({results:[]});
Also ensure the response from the server is coming back as an array not an object.