# Value doesn't change using setState() ,React nested API call

Tags: reactjs, api

The scenario is quite simple a first call will perform a "GET" request and setState() with the result, the second call will "POST" it.

Manaje.js

```
export default class Manage extends Component {
    static foo() {
        return adalApiFetch(fetch, 'api/Users/Generate', {
            method: "get",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/ json' }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    static update(np, sd) {
        return adalApiFetch(fetch, 'api/Users/Update', {
            method: "post",
            body: JSON.stringify({ np: np, sd: sd }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/ json' }
        });
    } }
```

Reset.js

```
export default class Reset extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { test: 'test' };
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
        this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
        this.handlefoo = this.handlefoo.bind(this);
    }

foo() {
    Manage.foo()
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ test: "result_from_foo" });
        });
}

update() {
    var np = this.state.test;

    Manage.Update(np, sd){
      //rest of the code
    }
}
 handlefoo() {
        this.foo();
        this.update();
    }

//=>habldefoo triggered later in the render()
// <div><Button onClick={this.handlefoo} disabled={this.state.selectAll === 0} bsStyle="success">foo</Button></div>
```

The error:

```
Error: value of this.state.test is always 'test' as set initially.
```

Comment: If i move the logic of foo() to the constructor this works but it get the value just once the page is refreshed which is not the workflow that i am trying to achieve

Comment: Have you tried using this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you want to call `update()` just after `foo()` finishes, right? As it is on your code, it will call both before `foo()` response arrives from the server.

You should use the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that you are returning on your ajax calls:

```
foo() {
    return Manage.foo() // return the promise that Manage.foo returns
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ test: "result_from_foo" });
        });
}

update() {
    var np = this.state.test;

    // you have a type error here, it must be update, not Update
    return Manage.update(np, sd).then(()=> { // return the promise that Manage.update returns
      //rest of the code, running after Manage.update returns
    });
}
handlefoo() {
    this.foo().then(() => { // here, call update just after foo completes
        this.update();
    });
}
```