# API request infinity. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch-api, openweathermap

I create weather application and use API openweathermap.
I fetch data from API, but network in console show infinity request.

My React code:

```
class CityWeather extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      city: "",
      temp: "",
      date: "Today"
    }
  }

  render() {
    const fetchWeatherData = location => {
        const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+location+'&units=metric&APPID=65ea63d33ba78059603a85cba8c80620';
        fetch(url).then(res =>
          res.json()
        ).then(data => {
          this.setState({
            city: data.city.name,
            temp: data.list[0].main.temp
          })
        })
      }

    return (
      <div>
        {fetchWeatherData(this.props.name)}
        <div>{this.state.city}</div>
        <div>{this.state.date}</div>
        <div>{this.state.temp}</div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fetching the weather data each time a render happens. When you get a response you change the state of the component via [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#setstate), which causes a re-render, and therefore results in an infinite loop.

Please see this post aswell: [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js)

Instead you should be fetching the weather data when the component mounts, which only happens once. See [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) in the docs.

```js
class CityWeather extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            city: "",
            temp: "",
            date: "Today"
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const fetchWeatherData = location => {
            const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+location+'&units=metric&APPID=65ea63d33ba78059603a85cba8c80620';
            fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({
                        city: data.city.name,
                        temp: data.list[0].main.temp
                    })
                })
        };
        fetchWeatherData(this.props.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.city}</div>
                <div>{this.state.date}</div>
                <div>{this.state.temp}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```