# react js hooks useEffect infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing around with react hooks and following the tutorail at https://www.valentinog.com/blog/hooks/. I put in the empty array as the second argument following the docs and some reason I'm still getting an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function useDataLoader() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data.value.joke)
        console.log(data)
      }, []);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {data}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Hook from './components/Hook'
import DataLoader from './components/DataLoader'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Hook />
        <DataLoader/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059059/react-hooks-making-an-ajax-request/53059214#53059214 (note that the other answers including the accepted answer are a bit outdated... mine is updated...) Let me know if you have questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` is in the wrong place. You pass it to `fetch().then()` instead of `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data.value.joke)
        console.log(data)
      });
  }, []);
```