# Infinity Loop with promises and state variables in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react component is rendering multiple times in infinity loop. What am I missing?

Here is my code.

```
const DocViewer = ({ title, closeModal }) => {

    const [docsSimilares, setDocsSimilares] = useState([]);
    const baseUrl = '/docs'

    async function similares() {
        return await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${title}`).then(data => setDocsSimilares(data.data.body.hits.hits[0]._source.documentos_similares))
    }
    
    similares().then(console.log(docsSimilares))

    return (
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column pdf">
                <h1>{title}</h1> 
                <PDFViewer url={sFileNameDemo} />
            </div>
            <div class="column semelhantes">
                <button onClick={closeModal} >Fechar</button>
                <p>{docsSimilares.map(doc => (
                    <div>
                        <p>{doc}</p>
                        <img alt={doc} src={doc} width="100%" />
                    </div>
                ))}</p>             
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DocViewer
```

Comment: post the full page but I can already see the problem

Comment: `.then(console.log(docsSimilares))` doesn't wait for the promise to resolve, it just calls `console.log` right away!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976759/1218980)

Answer (score 2):

When you call your `similares()` function you are setting state when calling `setDocsSimilares`.
By setting state you trigger re-render, when you trigger re-render it calls your `similares()` function again, that changes the state... You got the idea :)

By simply calling `similares()` inside of your functional component - it executes on each re-render.

You cannot just simply call similares() the way you do.
I think what you trying to achieve is to get data on first component mount, so you should use `useEffect` with empty array as second argument like so:

```
useEffect(() => similares().then(console.log(docsSimilares)),[])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks you need to understand [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
useEffect(() => similares().then(console.log(docsSimilares)),[])
```

The square brackets are where you add dependencies, if no dependencies it will only run on initializing "mounting" it is the same as `componentDidMount()` so that it will only fire the `async` request on load.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem:

```
    async function similares() {
    const simDocs = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${title}`).then(data => (data.data.body.hits.hits[0]._source.documentos_similares))
    setDocsSimilares(simDocs)
}

useEffect(() => {
                    similares().then(data => console.log(data))
                },[]);
```