# React Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,
i am trying to use async function but i have facing the following error
"**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**"

```
import {
  Badge,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Pagination,
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationLink,
  Table,
  Container,
  Row,
  UncontrolledTooltip,
} from "reactstrap";
// core components

import Header from "components/Headers/Header.js";
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";
import data from "./data";
var apitoken= localStorage.getItem('apitoken');

const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://IP/DeAPI/api/v1/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}

const asynchronousFunction = async () => {
  const response = await api.get("/",options)
 
  window.input=response.data.response


}

const mainFunction = async () => {
  const result = await asynchronousFunction()
  return result
}
const state = { students:window.input}
//console.log(window.input);
  const renderTableData=async ()=> {
    console.log("test"+await mainFunction())
    if(state.students) {
    
    
      return state.students.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <th scope="row">
                      <Media className="align-items-center">
                        <a
                          className="avatar rounded-circle mr-3"
                          href="#pablo"
                          onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          <img
                            alt="..."
                            src={
                              require("../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg")
                                .default
                            }
                          />
                        </a>
                        <Media>
                          <span className="mb-0 text-sm">{id}   </span>
                        </Media>
                      </Media>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{name}</Badge>
                    </td>
               <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{age}</Badge>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{email}</Badge>
                    </td>
                    
            </tr>
         )
      })
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
   }
  
const Accounts = () => {

 
  return (
    <>

      <Header />
      {/* Page content */}
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        {/* Table */}
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            <Card className="shadow">
              <CardHeader className="border-0">
                <h3 className="mb-0">All Account</h3>
              </CardHeader>
              <div>
          
          
         </div>
              <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
                <thead className="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Account Owner</th>
                    {/* <th scope="col">Pincode</th> */}
                    <th scope="col" />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {renderTableData()}
                 
                </tbody>
              </Table>
             
          
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Row>
       
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accounts;
```

What have i done wrong here;

I am trying to get the student data from api and render it in the component dynamically.

The issue is with

```
<tbody>
                {renderTableData()}
                 
                </tbody>
```

If i removed it its working,

Thanks in advance

Comment: please take a look on how API calls are made in react: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38742334/9321755

Comment: Why do you need window.input ?

Comment: I do not need window.input, i just verfied it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put anything except JSX into JSX. The problem is that `async function` returns Promise instead of JSX. You should rather use `React.useEffect` and `React.useState` to solve the loading problem. Let me show you.

Acutally another problem might be returning an array. Try wrapping it into `<>...</>` as I did.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Badge,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Pagination,
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationLink,
  Table,
  Container,
  Row,
  UncontrolledTooltip,
} from "reactstrap";
// core components

import Header from "components/Headers/Header.js";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";
import data from "./data";
var apitoken= localStorage.getItem('apitoken');

const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://IP/DeAPI/api/v1/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}

const TableData = () => {
  const [students, setStudents] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await api.get("/",options);
    setStudents(response.data.response);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []); 
  if (loading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }
    
  return (
    <>
      {students.map((student, index) => {
        const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <th scope="row">
              <Media className="align-items-center">
                <a
                  className="avatar rounded-circle mr-3"
                  href="#pablo"
                  onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                >
                  <img
                    alt="..."
                    src={
                      require("../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg")
                        .default
                    }
                  />
                </a>
                <Media>
                  <span className="mb-0 text-sm">{id}   </span>
                </Media>
              </Media>
            </th>
            <td>
              <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{name}</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{age}</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{email}</Badge>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
  
const Accounts = () => {
 return (
    <>

      <Header />
      {/* Page content */}
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        {/* Table */}
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            <Card className="shadow">
              <CardHeader className="border-0">
                <h3 className="mb-0">All Account</h3>
              </CardHeader>
              <div>
          
          
         </div>
              <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
                <thead className="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Account Owner</th>
                    {/* <th scope="col">Pincode</th> */}
                    <th scope="col" />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <TableData />
                 
                </tbody>
              </Table>
             
          
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Row>
       
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accounts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the lifecycle hook `useEffect` to fetch async data (when working with functional components).

you also want to save your data in `state`. This is the default way to work with apis in react. Simply storing it in a variable will not work due to React's async behaviour.

Your error here is that you are trying to render a promise, which is not valid JSX

you can use the hook like this

```
const [state, setState] = useState({})
...
useEffect(() =>{
async(() =>{
   const data = await mainFunction()
   setState(data)
})()
}, []) //empty array means to only run once
```

Comment: The issue is with <tbody>
                {renderTableData()}
                 
                </tbody>.If i remove the renderTableData its working

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
{state.students?.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <th scope="row">
                      <Media className="align-items-center">
                        <a
                          className="avatar rounded-circle mr-3"
                          href="#pablo"
                          onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          <img
                            alt="..."
                            src={
                              require("../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg")
                                .default
                            }
                          />
                        </a>
                        <Media>
                          <span className="mb-0 text-sm">{id}   </span>
                        </Media>
                      </Media>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{name}</Badge>
                    </td>
               <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{age}</Badge>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Badge color="" className="badge-dot mr-4">{email}</Badge>
                    </td>
                    
            </tr>
         )
      }) 
} 
</tbody>
```

Try this one instead

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is not really a clean way to solve this problem in react...

Comment: Try the new answer,