# React: Asynchronous Functional components work in some situations but not others

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, react-suspense

I am having an issue with NextJS and React where asynchronous functional components "work" within the app directory, but gives me the seemingly popular `"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."` error when used within the pages directory.

Both components are attempting to render the same asynchronous functional component.

According to how I understood this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56213291/10438501) and this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814925/10438501) what I did in page.js and componentA.js shouldn't be possible at all so I am not sure how it properly renders a component in one situation but tries to render a promise causing it to fail in the other. From what I have read I think I understand why it fails when it fails, just not why it works when it works and what the difference between the situations is.

Big picture is I have to use a bunch of components that a coworker made in a previous project in the style of page.js and componentA.js, which works fine in their original application, but the current project needs things in equivalents of initial.js where everything falls apart. Is there something I can do to avoid rewriting everything?

Relevant Files

project/src/pages/initial.js

```
"use client"
import  { Fragment, Suspense } from 'react'
import MyContextProvider from '@/app/mycontext'
import ComponentA from "../app/componentA"
export default function Initial() {

  return (
    <Fragment>
    <MyContextProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading</span>}>
      <ComponentA suppressHydrationWarning={true} ></ComponentA>
      </Suspense>
    </MyContextProvider>
   </Fragment>
  )
}
```

project/src/app/page.js

```
"use client"

import ComponentA from './componentA'
import MyContextProvider from './mycontext'
import { Fragment, Suspense } from 'react'
import Initial from '../pages/initial'
export default function Home() {
  return (
   <Fragment>
    <MyContextProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading</span>}>
      <ComponentA suppressHydrationWarning={true} ></ComponentA>
      </Suspense>
    </MyContextProvider>
{/*<Initial></Initial>*/}
   </Fragment>
  )
}
```

project/src/app/componentA.js

```
"use client"
async function getNewData() {
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1' ,)
return data.json()
}
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react'

export default async function ComponentA(filters) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("useEffect")
    })
    let apiReturn = await getNewData()


return(
    <Fragment>{apiReturn.title}
    <>--A</></Fragment>
)
}
```

**Things I have tried**

The co-worker who wrote the working asynchronous code told me that hooks cannot be used in async components so I put the useEffect there, to try and break it, but that made no difference.

initial.js did not originally use React Suspense and I thought that may have been the issue but adding in the suspense tag changed nothing. It is my understanding that React Suspense renders a temporary component until the intended component is available, and its intended use is for components that take a while to render which would include asynchronous components which I assume would have to return a promise. If that is the case then why is initial.js giving me issues? Or is Suspense only supposed to be passed regular components as children?

In case there was something in page.js and not in initial.js I copied the return statement from one to the other to make sure they matched exactly, which did not change anything

I imported initial.js into page.js and used it as a component (this is what is commented out in the code I provided) it did work and showed componentA twice. This makes me think there is some dependency that page.js gets and initial.js does not unless it has page.js as a parent that resolves the issue. {EDIT at of 10/02/2023} I no longer believe this to be the case, in my continued testing I found that removing the async component from initial.js and importing page.js into initial.js does not work so that proves the previous guess wrong.

when it goes Layout.js > page.js > componentA.js -- everything works

when it goes Layout.js > initial.js > componentA.js -- I get the error

when it goes Layout.js > page.js > componentA.js & initial.js > componentA.js -- everything works

when it goes Layout.js > initial.js > page.js > componentA.js -- the error occurs.