# Viewing backend data in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Given is an application with 3 pages:

- "Mainpage"
- "PrivatPage"
- "UserManagementPage"

and a file for communication with the backend:

- "ManagementAction.js"

After successful login the user is redirected to a *"PrivatPage"*. On the *"PrivatPage"* the user has the possibility to go to the *"UserManagementPage"*.

**PrivatPage.js**

```
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";

import LogoutButton from "./LogoutButton";
import UserManagementButton from "./UserManagementButton";
import ManagementSessionWidget from './UserManagementSessionWidget'
import UserManagementPage from './UserManagementPage'
import {
  NavBar,
  LinkContainer
} from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"

class PrivatePage extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <
      div className = "page-content"
      id = "PrivatePage"
      style = {
        {
          background: 'white'
        }
      } >

      
      <
      br / > Private Page <
      br / >
      <
      Router >

      <
      Button > < Link to = "/user"
      id = "OpenUserManagementButton" >
      <
      i className = "fa fa-user mr-2 fa-fw activityBarItem" > <
      /i>UserManagement</Link > < /Button> <
      Routes >

      <
      Route path = "/user"
      element = {
        < UserManagementPage / >
      }
      />

      <
      /Routes> <
      /Router>

      <
      /div>       

    )
  }
}

export default PrivatePage
```

However, when the *"UserManagementPage"* is opened, the backend data should appear on the page.
Access to the backend data works. The *"ManagementAction.js"* file is used for this purpose

**ManagementAction.js**

```
export function showallUser(){

    console.log("Show all Users")
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getShowUserManagementAction());
        showUser().then(userSession => { const action= getShowUserManagementActionSuccess(userSession);
        dispatch(action);}, error => {dispatch(getShowUserManagementErrorAction(error));}).catch(error=> {dispatch(getShowUserManagementErrorAction(error));})
    }

    
}

function showUser() {
    const hash="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJEZWZhdWx0IEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IgQWNjb3VudCIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjE2NDE1NjgyNzgxNDUsImlhdCI6MTY0MTU2Nzk3OH0.mJff9nuqgHXZVQfWbjeWed3JIRAm2N2s0CYpnXoMyv4"
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}` },
        
        }; 
        
         
return fetch('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
.then(handleResponse)
.then(userSession => {
return userSession;
});


}
```

I also tried to get the data from the API on the *"UserManagementPage"* with the help of the axios module. The data only do not arrive again,the `console.log` output returns an empty array.

```
   class UserManagementPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {userList: []}
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("I will get called once the page gets loaded");
        const hash="whatever"
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}` },
        
        };
        const response =  await axios.get('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions);
        this.setState({ userList: response.data.results });
        console.log(this.state.userList)
    }}
```

How do I map the data to the *"UserManagementPage"* now ?

Answer (score 1):

to get the data from backend in **UserManagementPage.js** you should use the **useEffect** hook in which you will call your functions **showUser** or **showAllUser**.

Here is the link of doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Hooks won't work, Pawl123  seems to be using class components. If you want to use hooks, make sure your UserManagementPage is a functional component, or instead call the showUser / showAllUsers methods from the componentDidMount lifecycle method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js

Comment: Just now I tried to get the data directly on the UserManagementPage using the Axios module. Unfortunately it did not work. I have extended my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a capitalisation mismatch in your state? You initialise it as `userlist`, but then set the state under the key `userList`. The console log returns an empty array because the state variable you initialise never gets updated.

Comment: I correct this mistake and update the post. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The successful fetching of data from the API was achieved with the following method:

```
   getUsersData() {

        const hash="whatever"
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}` },
            
            };
        axios
            .get('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data
                console.log(data)
                
                const users = data.map(u =>
                    <div>
                    <p>{u.userID}</p>
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    )

                    this.setState({
                        users
                    })

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
    }
```