# Replace string word with useState variable React.Js

Tags: reactjs

Hello I need replace word in string with react state variable and hold the reference: example:

```
Const [mystate, setMyState] = useState({user:"miuser",html:""});

let htmlString = getHtmlStringFromApi(); // get "<p>{{username}}</p>"

//I try

setMyState(...mystate, html: htmlString.replace("{{username}}", mystate.user));

return(

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mystate.html}}></div>

)
```

The problem is that the state html var changes; My div doesnt change. Any idea to replace with state by reference? Thanks

Comment: Is this the actual code ?  If not can you please post the actual code you are using. I can see some syntax errors in the code you have posted.

Comment: Hello , is the part of code that I have a trouble, sorry the code is too big but this is the main idea ; I can't replace this Word with state by reference

Comment: In above code you are not setting the state correctly. You are not passing object to `setMyState()`. It should be like this: `setMyState({ ...mystate, html: htmlString.replace("{{username}}", mystate.user) });`

Comment: Also `getHtmlStringFromApi()` looks like an asynchronous API call which returns a `Promise` so you will need to use `await` or `then()` to wait for the API data and then set your state.

Comment: You can refer to this post for how to make API calls : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js

Comment: Hello sorry for the example; yes this method need await but this code is like a pseudo code; the point is that the replace doesnt set the reference of the state in the string; because only set the text; I need set the reference ; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you can use the `useEffect()` hook with dependency array to reflect the changes of `state` in the html string. So whenever the `htmlString` is updated, your state will also get updated with new html.

```
const [htmlString, setHtmlString] = useState("");
const [mystate, setMyState] = useState({user:"miuser",html:""});

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await getHtmlStringFromApi(); // get "<p>{{username}}</p>"
      setHtmlString(res);
    };
  
    getData();
}, []);

// This will update the html in mystate whenever htmlString is updated
useEffect(() => {
    setMyState({ ...mystate, html: htmlString.replace("{{username}}", mystate.user) });
}, [htmlString]);

return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mystate.html}}></div>
)
```

Comment: Great Answer, problem solve, thank you