# Accessing and looping through data in Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a promise from Fetch that I use to get the list of countries from our API:

```
async fetchDataFromAPI () {
    console.log('fetchDataFromAPI')
    let response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BRIDGEMAN_API_URL + '/countries',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
    let data = await response.json();
    return data
}
```

I call that promise inside of a class component in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({countries: this.fetchDataFromAPI()})
}
```

Then when I pass it to the render function, Like this:

```
const {
    countries
} = this.state

console.log('state countries', countries)
```

I get the following output in my console:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
                <state>: "fulfilled"
                    <value>: Array(244) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
                        [0…99]
                        [100…199]
                        [200…243]
                        length: 244
                        <prototype>: Array []
                            <prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

All the data is there in the ''.  I just dont know how to get at it?

I've tried `countries.then((data) => {console.log('data', data)})` but I get the message that countries has no method `.then`.  I've tried `countries.map` and that is the same error.

How can I loop through and output the data on the page?

Comment: Put `await`  while calling method `this.setState({countries: await this.fetchDataFromAPI()})`

Comment: Async functions ALWAYS return a promise. So you need to await it's response like `wait this.fetchDataFromAPI()`

Comment: See: [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353630)

Comment: @NickParsons I do use the fetch inside the componentDidMount, just like the link you sent me said

Comment: @RichardBridge No, you're doing it differently to what the link I sent suggests, the equivalent would be `this.fetchDataFromAPI().then((data) => this.setState({countries: data}))`