# Client-server connection in a node.JS app

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, fetch-api

I am checking out how CORS works and reviewing the basics of the client-server concept in a node.JS app. And I have a question.

Here is my code for the server:

```
const express = require('express'),
      server = express(),
      cors = require('cors');

server.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000"}));

server.get('/json-data', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send([
            {order:10,value:29},
            {order:100,value:541},
            {order:1000,value:7919}])
});

server.listen(8888);
```

By pointing the web browser to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/json-data
```

I can confirm that the server is working as expected, returning an array of 3 items.

My question is going to relate to the client.

When I use the code hereafter for the client:

```
'use client'

function Receiver() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8888/json-data")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Receiver-0:'+JSON.stringify(data[0]))
    console.log('Receiver-1:'+JSON.stringify(data[1]))
    console.log('Receiver-2:'+JSON.stringify(data[2]))
  })

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Receiver !!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I get the answer I expect in the web browser:

```
Hello Receiver !!
```

And I see the 3 expected items in the logs (i.e. The web developer tools console).

On the other hand if I use this code  for the client:

```
async function Receiver() {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8888/json-data");
  const primes = await response.json();
  const data = JSON.stringify(primes)
  return <h1>{data}</h1>;
}

export default Receiver;
```

I get this answer in the web browser:

```
[{"order":10,"value":29},{"order":100,"value":541}]
```

Why am I not getting the three items from the server and only two ?

Taking the 2 versions of client above as a starting point, is there a way to lay down my code so that I receive in the answer all the items that the server provides ?

As an extra piece of information, this is how the client is used:

```
import Receiver from './components/receiver'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>
        <Receiver />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I have also tried the code below for the client (based on the code found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch)

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/json-data')

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }

  return res.json()
}

export default async function Receiver() {
  const data = await getData()

  return <main>{JSON.stringify(data)}</main>
}
```

But I still get the same result as the previous trial. This answer in the web browser:

```
[{"order":10,"value":29},{"order":100,"value":541}]
```

Comment: Is the client-side a React (or more likely Next.js) app? Is `Receiver` used as a component (`<Receiver />`) or just a regular function (`Receiver()`) that happens to return JSX? How are you calling `Receiver`? I strongly suspect you'll need to use state and your question is a duplicate of [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38742334/283366)

Comment: @Phil. Yes the client-side is a Next.js app. I added some information to the post, please have a look.

Comment: See also https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

Comment: Your last link does not seem to work as I just added in the post.

Comment: Did you try setting the `cache: 'no-store'` property for the server-side fetch [as per the docs I linked](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching)?

Comment: No. I hadn't. Now it all works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the request on the client-side where CORS is actually important, you need to use React state and an effect hook. This is because client-side components cannot be async functions; they must use React's state lifecycle to provide live updates.

```jsx
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const fetchPrimes = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/json-data');
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetch failed: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default function Receiver() {
  const [primes, setPrimes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPrimes().then(setPrimes).catch(console.error);
  }, []); // run once on mount

  return <main>{JSON.stringify(primes)}</main>;
}
```

---

Alternately, you can use Next.js async server components. You may want to [disable caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching) if you feel you're getting stale data

```jsx
const fetchPrimes = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/json-data', {
    cache: 'no-store', //  disable caching
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetch failed: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Receiver() {
  const primes = await fetchPrimes()

  return <main>{JSON.stringify(primes)}</main>
}
```