# Can I use async call with useState(functionName)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

Learning react so please bear with...

Below code works for me and allows me to set the valueOne as OneOneOne

```
import react from "React";

function LoadPage() {
  const [valueOne, setvalueOne] = useState(GetValueOne);

  function GetValueOne() {
    return "OneOneOne";
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is I need to make a call to the server to return the actual value of valueOne on page load... So I have changed to the following:

```
async function GetValueOne() {
  let oneResult;

  await axios.get(`${getBaseUrl()}/One/GetValueOfOne`).then((res) => {
    oneResult = res.data;
  });

  return oneResult;
}
```

This is now not working as I have changed the function to async to wait for the axios.get request...Can I update the useState to match this?

If not is there another way to do this please?

Comment: From the duplicate (which is quite old), scroll down to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976759/283366) which covers function components and hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [UseEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hook in ReactJS. You can initialize the state with null value and then update it once the component mounts for the first time.

**Sample code:**

```
 const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${getBaseUrl()}/One/GetValueOfOne`);
        setValueOne(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching valueOne:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

On above useEffect, I have added empty square bracket which means useEffect only run once when component mounts.

**Here, is full code implementation:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function LoadPage() {
  const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${getBaseUrl()}/One/GetValueOfOne`);
        setValueOne(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching valueOne:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to only run once on mount

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Value of valueOne: {valueOne}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoadPage;
```

Let me know, If you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, this has resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useEffect` in this case.

You can initialize the state with some dummy value inside `useState` and add a an effect to update the state value

```js
function LoadPage() {
  
  const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState({})  
  
  useEffect(() => {
  
    async function getValueOne() {
      const oneResult = await axios.get(`${getBaseUrl()}/One/GetValueOfOne`)
      setValueOne(oneResult.data)
    }
    getValueOne()
    
  }, [])
  
}
```

Alternatively, if your project is getting bigger

1. You can take a look at some data fetching/management libraries like Tanstack Query, SWR etc..
2. You can also take a look at global state solutions like Redux coupled with middlewares like Thunk / Saga for data fetching