# How to loop though db objects in React?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, object

How can I make LINE #1 to work?

Cookie

```
function GetBrandData() {

    var jsonData = "";

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData5() {
        const response = await fetch(variables.API_URL);
        jsonData = await response.json();
        alert(JSON.stringify({ jsonData }));

        /* The line above shows the following output
            {
                "jsonData": [{ "id": 1, "name": "ASUS", "isSelected": false },
                    { "id": 2, "name": "DELL", "isSelected": true },
                    { "id": 3, "name": "HP", "isSelected": true },
                    { "id": 4, "name": "Lenovo", "isSelected": false },
                    { "id": 5, "name": "MSI", "isSelected": false }]
            }
            */                  
    
        }
        getData5();

    }, [])
       
    return (jsonData);   

}

<>

var listBrands = GetBrandData();


// LINE #1
{listBrands.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value=  {brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>)};  
</>
```

I am trying to loop thought objects come from db.

And I have tried some methods found online. But
it still does not work.

I still having problem with LINE #1. Please see the error message I got as shown below. Thanks.

> Compiled with problems: × ERROR in ./src/App.js Module build failed
> (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
> C:\Users\33ebo\FrontEnd5React\f5\src\App.js: Unexpected token,
> expected "," (58:23)
>
> 56 | 57 | // LINE #1
>
> 58 | return { listBrands.map(brand => {}{brand.name}) }; | ^ 59 | 60 |
> } 61 | .......... ERROR [eslint] src\App.js Line 58:23: Parsing error:
> Unexpected token, expected "," (58:23) .......... Line 58 is shown
> below: // LINE #1 return { listBrands.map(brand => {}{brand.name}) };

Comment: From the alert result i think you need to use `jsonData.jsonData.map` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976759/283366). You need to use state and store the API result into it

Comment: @LãNgọcHải no, that's just showing like that because OP used `{ jsonData }`, aka `{ jsonData: jsonData }`

Comment: @Phil i see, thanks for poiting out.

Comment: I try both below return statements, one at a time. I still get error:

return (
        <>
            {jsonData.jsonData.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value={brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>)}
        </>
    );

----------------------

return (
        <>
            {jsonData:jsonData.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value={brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>)}
        </>
    );

Answer (score -1):

Few things that are not correct with your code.

1. useEffect should not be inside any function, it should be in the top level for the component. read [this](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#caveats)
2. The component only renders once on mount if you don't have any states that are changing, in your code listBrands will not make the component re render when data is fetched as you are not using it as state.

Your code should look something like this.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [listBrands, setListBrands] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function getData5() {
    const response = await fetch(variables.API_URL);
    jsonData = await response.json();
    alert(JSON.stringify({ jsonData }));
    setListBrands(jsonData);
    setLoading(false);

        /* The line above shows the following output
            {
                "jsonData": [{ "id": 1, "name": "ASUS", "isSelected": false },
                    { "id": 2, "name": "DELL", "isSelected": true },
                    { "id": 3, "name": "HP", "isSelected": true },
                    { "id": 4, "name": "Lenovo", "isSelected": false },
                    { "id": 5, "name": "MSI", "isSelected": false }]
            }
            */
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData5();
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

const handleCpusCheckbox = () => {
  // Do something here
}

// LINE #1
return listBrands.map(brand => (
      <div>
        <input
          key={brand.id}
          type="checkbox"
          value={brand.name}
          onChange={handleCpusCheckbox}
        />

        {brand.name}
      </div>
    ))
```

Here useEffect is run when component mounts, it runs the function `getData5` and inside the function it sets the data to listBrands, this triggers rerender of the component and you will have your data this time and mapping the component will work as expected.

Comment: Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\33ebo\FrontEnd5React\f5\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:23)
  
  57 |     // LINE #1
> 58 |     return { listBrands.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value={brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>) };  
                     ^
  ...........

ERROR
[eslint] 
src\App.js
  Line 58:23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:23)

Note: Line 58 is LINE #1.

Thanks.

Comment: have you defined this `handleCpusCheckbox` function? have edited the code above

Comment: Yes, I did use your code. I did define const handleCpusCheckbox = (e) => { const value = e.target.value; if (e.target.checked) { setCpusState([...cpusState, value]); } else {
            setCpusState(cpusState.filter(item => item !== value)); 
        }
    }

Comment: The problem is the "." (dot) between listBrands and map on LINE #1

Comment: the you can use question mark operator, `listBrands?.map`, but I don't think it should give compilation error

Comment: LINE #1 still give error. ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\33ebo\FrontEnd5React\f5\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:23)

  56 |
  57 |     // LINE #1
> 58 |     return { listBrands?.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value={brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>) };  
     |                        ^
  59 |
  60 | }
.........
ERROR
[eslint] 
src\App.js
  Line 58:23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:23)

Comment: I think this error tells where it is breaking, In line number 58 at position 23, I think it was the semicolon, have removed it

Comment: Remove semicolon. Still does not work. The problem is the "." (dot) between listBrands and map in or on the return statement

Answer (score -1):

Don't think too complex, make it easy by merging this two diff function and component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function GetBrandData() {

    const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData5() {
        const response = await fetch(variables.API_URL).then((res) => res.json());
        setJsonData(response);

        console.log(response);

        alert("NEW CODE (1): " + JSON.stringify(response));

            /* My database structure is below:
               [
                        { "id": 1, "name": "ASUS", "isSelected": false },
                        { "id": 2, "name": "DELL", "isSelected": true },
                        { "id": 3, "name": "HP", "isSelected": true },
                        { "id": 4, "name": "Lenovo", "isSelected": false },
                        { "id": 5, "name": "MSI", "isSelected": false }
                    ]
                
                */
        }
        getData5();

    }, [])

const handleCpusCheckbox = (e) => {
    alert("e = " + e.target.checked);        
}    

    return (
        <>
            {jsonData.map(brand => <div>{<input key={brand.id} type='checkbox' value={brand.name} onChange={handleCpusCheckbox} />}{brand.name}</div>)}
        </>
    );
}

export default GetBrandData;
```

1. make sure that after getting db response, data type of jsonData will keep remain `Array` as it is by destruct of complex response.
2. you have to `use state to re-render component` to load new UI with new input(db response).
3. handle your alert conditionally to don't reload your project every time. it can create infinite loop.

Comment: I add two alerts into your code (see your code above) and get the following results:
NEW CODE (1): {"jsonData":[]}
NEW CODE (2): [object Object]
And I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at GetBrandData (App.js:114:1)
    at App (App.js:222:1)
........

Comment: error shows that you don't get `array of object` you get multiple objects so add `console.log()` after `fetch()` in above edited code and **make sure that you get `array of db object` as your commented output**.

Comment: Hello Er. Bharat Jograna
I am new to React. If possible, please provide me the code. Thanks!